# Magento2 processing orders collection

Tags: magento2, orders, collection

I want to fetch the processing orders, How to fetch the processing orders collection in Magento2.

Thanks
Bestregards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use this code:**

```
Class : Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History
 /**
     * @return bool|\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    public function getOrders()
    {
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['eq' => 'Processing']
            );
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }
```